# In Clause limit in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, where-in

i am dynamically forming a query in oracle to select data where i give id's as input's. my query goes is as follows

```
select * from temp where temp_id in ( :Id);
```

my input id are in thousands so i am dynamically creating the in clause in such a way that my final query is as follows

```
select * 
from temp
where temp_id in (a1,a2,a3,....a999) 
  or temp_id in (b1,b2,b3,....b999) or so on ....
```

my problem here is even after that i am getting too many values exception.
Can you please help me.

Comment: I suspect the problem lies in your attempt to break up your list of id's.  Also, you might want to cover the situation where there are no id's.  I usually do that with `where 1 = 2 or temp_id in (list of id's) etc`.

Comment: Where does your list of thousands of IDs come from? Presumably not a human being typing them at a screen. In which case there is the opportunity to do something cleverer, depending on your architecture.

Comment: @APC , My Id's come as part of a java code .I just wanted to make my question easy.

Comment: so what, a string? an array?

Comment: @APC, It's a list of Objects.

Comment: So we slowly inch towards clarity. How do you call the SQL? Is it embedded in the Java layer? Do you have privileges to create database objects? "I just wanted to make my question easy". Next time consider making your question complete: it's easier for everybody in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use global temporary table:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table (
  id           NUMBER
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;

-- multiple INSERT INTO

select * from temp where temp_id in (SELECT id FROM my_temp_table);
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

to do it with a single request

```
select * from temp where id in (
    select a.letter||b.num from (
        select chr(rownum + 96) letter from dual connect by rownum < 3
    ) a 
    join (
        select rownum as num from dual connect by rownum < 1000
    ) b on 1=1
);
```

and you replace the value after "rownum <" with the number of letters you want + 1 (same thing for numbers)